# Why stream downloaders can't download from some streaming websites?

Tags: video-streaming, streaming

A lot of websites use streaming protocols to stream video content to their users. The main reason might be performance, however protecting the content might be also another reason.

A couple of tools exist to help download streaming videos. For example [Stream Video Downloader](https://www.stream-video-downloader.com/welcome/) Chrome extension. (I'm not related to this extension in any way).

It works great on a lot of sites. But in some sites it fails to detect or provide download link for the video. For example, it can't download from this site:

https://artgrid.io/clip/98825/cars-driving-around-and-parking-in-a-parking-lot-timelapse

Though it uses the `.ts` URL extensions and `.m3u8` streaming protocol (I don't know about these protocols).

What is different in these sites that prevent these extensions from working?

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself. It is using a different steaming format that the extension does not support.  What is preventing it from working, is lack of a programmer adding support for that format or site.